# Error while creating datasource in spring boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

Hi I am new to spring boot and trying to create a simple project but I am getting following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error 
>       creating bean with name 
>       'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.
>       HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': 
>       Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested 
>       exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
>       creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
>       [com/sears/web/security/JpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean 
>       failed; nested exception is 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
>       with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested 
>       exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
>       org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean.
>       afterPropertiesSet()V     at 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.
>       createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans- 
>       4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
>       ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
>   ~ 
>       [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]  at 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
>       AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor
>       (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans- 
>       4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
>   AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
>       createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [com/sears/web/security/JpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()V
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()V
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()V
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.doGetResources(DataSourceInitializer.java:163)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.getResources(DataSourceInitializer.java:147)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.getScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:87)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]

I am also adding pom.xml and DB configuration class

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
     <groupId>XXXXXXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>spring-boot-web-mvc</name>
  <description>
    Configure spring boot starter project for Web MVC as a WAR file, still 
  self executing.
 </description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.mvmlabs.springboot.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
 </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- Added to allow configuration as a web MVC, built as a WAR file (still 
executable) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- Add Apache Tiles into the mix -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<!-- <dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency> -->
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api - 
 ->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

DB configuration java file

```
  {
 @Configuration
 @EntityScan("com.sears")
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})

  public class JpaConfiguration {

@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") String driverClassName;
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}") String url;
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}") String username;
@Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String password;

@Bean(name = "dataSource")

public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("inside data source");

    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .url(url)
            .driverClassName(driverClassName)
            .build();
    return dataSource;
}
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new 
 LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.sears");
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
        SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new 
 HibernateTransactionManager(
            sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}   
@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource 
 dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return initializer;
}
```

}

Please help me with this issue. Sorry I couldn't format stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class SortedResourcesFactoryBean was implementing FactoryBean till version 3.0.1.RELEASE.
3.0.2.RELEASE onwards it started extending AbstractFactoryBean class which contain the method afterPropertiesSet().

Update your maven version of org.springframework from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```